# Table records get replaced when copying from another table in sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

I have two sqlite tables

tab1 (items (text),  Id (Integer primary key))

tab2 (items (text),  Id (Integer primary key))

tab1 has some records already. I want copy all records from tab2  that are not in tab1.

when I use the following query:

"insert into tab1 select * from tab2 where items not in (select items from tab1)".

It replaces all the items in tab1 with same PK from tab2.

I want new items from tab2 to be added into tab1 with new PK

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you want only the column `items` inserted in `tab1`. 
The other column `id`, since it is `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, it is also `AUTOINCREMENT`, so no special action for it is needed.

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (items)
SELECT items
FROM tab2 
WHERE items NOT IN (SELECT items FROM tab1)
```

or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (items)
SELECT items
FROM tab2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tab1 WHERE items = t2.items
)
```

Comment: You may consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.